# Query Data on Cosmos db with efcore

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb, ef-core-3.0

i am trying to query data from cosmos db with efcore. Where i want to pass multiple expressions to filter the record. My expressions are like:

```
public void GetData(){

Expression<Func<MyEntity, bool>> val1 = _ => _.Id== 1234;
Expression<Func<MyEntity, bool>> val2 = _ => _.reviewer == "username";

var abc = Or(val1,val2);

dbcontext.GetItemAsync(abc);
}

private static Expression<Func<MyEntity, bool>> 
Or(Expression<Func<MyEntity, bool>> expr1, 
Expression<Func<MyEntity, bool>> expr2)
{
    var body = Expression.OrElse(expr1.Body, expr2.Body);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<MyEntity, bool>>(body, expr1.Parameters[0]);
}
```

---

while doing so it always throws error that _ is not defined.
Please help.

Comment: Please format your code correctly so it can be easily read - the snippet you posted won't even compile (e.g. because there is `()` missing after `GetData`)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft have created a database provider for cosmos-db [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/cosmos/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli, although it only supports the SQL API for now